# Kotion Each G2000 headset not working by USB

Tags: usb, sound, microphone

I've got a Kotion Each G2000 headset that works when connected through jacks (not the mic though), but I have absolutely no hint about how to make it work through USB (Mic and Sound). Can't find any guide as well.

**I've tried all headset questions in AskUbuntu without luck**, no questions for this particular device.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sadly there won't be any way the question can be answered in favor of your bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is pretty short but nothing you'd want to hear:

**The Kotion Each G2000's USB is only for the light!**

See the [product description on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00Q8M8E3E?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00#productDetails):

"Headset interface: USB (plug the USB connector, LED light is on, unplug, it off) + 3.5mm stereo"

To make it work, you simply have to use the 3.5mm stereo ports.

Comment: Additional source: I had the same headset and the same problems.

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDIN'? Can't believe it man...Anyways this solved my question, you told me the answer: it's not possible to make them work. The bounty is yours buddy ;-)

Comment: No, I'm not, sorry. That's probably a reason why they are so cheap..